# Spinner giving me a NullPointerException error

Tags: android, android-spinner

The code is straight from the android docs.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class AddActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.post_types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

**problem**
spinner.setAdapter(adapter); is returning the error.

**layout**

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

**logcat**

```
02-17 01:57:48.932  25293-25293/com.example.project.thisthat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.thisthat, PID: 25293
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.project.thisthat/com.example.project.thisthat.AddActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.project.thisthat.AddActivity.onCreate(AddActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**edit**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">"This That"</string>
    <string name="title_section1">Section 1</string>
    <string name="title_section2">Section 2</string>
    <string name="title_section3">Section 3</string>
    <string name="title_activity_add">Add</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

    <string-array name="post_types">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
        <item>7</item>
        <item>8</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: spinner is null.  Are you sure you're using the right id?

Comment: @EricLemos Is that `spinner` in **activity_add.xml** ?

Comment: @HariharanTamilan its in fragment_add.xml

Comment: If it is in fragment_add then you have to find it in your **PlaceholderFragment** class

Comment: check your adapter values..! i think value of array is null

Comment: @PiyushGupta updated with logcat

Comment: have u checked this R.array.post_types have values in the String.xml

Comment: which is line 30 in AddActivity.class? post that

Comment: @EricLemos will u please post the fragment_add.xml file

Comment: your code is working fine on my device .i have just commented this line inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);.so i just want to cross check everything is looking good.there is no error .Please clean your project once .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that NPE do that codes should inside `PlaceholderFragment`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container,false);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.post_types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: that removes the error, but the spinner isn't populated.

Comment: @EricLemos Is `R.array.post_types` having items?

Comment: @HariharanTamilanyes, I updated the question to show my strings.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container,false);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String[] mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.post_types);    
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, mTestArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

Hope it will help you.